Restructuring data with occurrences of factors into data for network analysis based on co-occurrence
I am trying to restructure my data based on co-occurrence of some factors (the purpose is network analysis with nodes and edges). In my dataset I have the value ‘1’ whenever a patient with an ID has occurrence for each of these factors.
The dataframe below is just an example, not the actual dataset. The actual dataset has more variables and more observations.
I am trying to produce a dataset with a different data structure that gives me the value of the ID when there is co-existence of two factors, such as when John has both bmi_100=1 and also crp_100=1.
In the provided demo data you can see that John and Jeff have both bmi_100=1 and crp_100=1. Therefore, in the new dataset, I would like a variable "bmi_100.crp_100" that has the observations ‘John’ and ‘Jeff’ (i.e. a variable name based on two variable names from the previous dataset and a "." separator between these). Each variable name should consist of the combination of variables in the original data with a separator. Variables in the new dataset should include all possible combinations of variables from the original dataset.
Below I have made a demo of existing data structure and below that the new structure that I try to achieve:
# What I have: unique IDs and occurrences for each variable
id <- c("John", "Cindy", "Laura", "Jeff", "Amy")
bmi_100  <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
crp_100  <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
eur <-      c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
cdai_rem <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
df1 <- data.frame(id, bmi_100, crp_100, eur, cdai_rem)
print(df1)

# What I try to get: for each co-occurrence put ID if co-occurrence and the rest of the observations put "0" to allow merging into dataframe)
bmi_100.crp_100  <- c("John", "Jeff", 0, 0, 0)
bmi_100.eur      <- c("John", "Laura", "Jeff", 0, 0)
bmi_100.cdai_rem <- c("John", "Cindy", "Jeff", 0, 0)
crp_100.eur      <- c("John", "Jeff", "Amy", 0, 0)
crp_100.cdai_rem <- c("John", "Jeff", 0, 0, 0)
eur.cdai_rem     <- c("John", "Jeff", 0, 0, 0)
df3 <- data.frame(bmi_100.crp_100, bmi_100.eur, bmi_100.cdai_rem, crp_100.eur, 
crp_100.cdai_rem)
print(df3)


Not a short, super-concise, base-R answer, but done is better than perfect.
Despite being a tidyverse solution, it's main point is the utils::combn function. Check it out.
Pkgs and toy data:
library(tidyverse)

# Toy data --------------------
toy_df <- structure(
  list(
    id = c("John", "Cindy", "Laura", "Jeff", "Amy"), 
    bmi_100 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0), 
    crp_100 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1), 
    eur = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1), 
    cdai_rem = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0)), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -5L))

The code:
# Step 1: Longer, tidy format
new_df <- toy_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  arrange(id, name) %>% 
  filter(value !=0)

# Step 2: Finding all combinations with `utils::combn`
new_df <- reframe(new_df, .by = c(id, value), comb = list(combn(name, 2)))

# Step 3: Wrangling and formatting combinations' names
new_df <- new_df %>% 
  mutate(
    comb = map(
      comb, 
      \(x_comb) map_chr(
        1:ncol(x_comb), 
        \(x_col) str_flatten(x_comb[, x_col], collapse = ".")))) %>% 
  
  unnest(comb)

# Step 4: Wider format
new_df <- new_df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = comb, values_from = value) %>% 
  mutate(across(-id, \(x) if_else(x == 1, id, as.character(x))))

# Step 5: Sorting names and replacing NAs
new_df <- map_dfc(2:ncol(new_df), \(x) arrange(new_df[, x], across(1))) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), \(x) replace_na(x, "0")))

The output:
> new_df
# A tibble: 5 × 6
  crp_100.eur bmi_100.cdai_rem bmi_100.crp_100 bmi_100.eur cdai_rem.crp_100
  <chr>       <chr>            <chr>           <chr>       <chr>           
1 Amy         Cindy            Jeff            Jeff        Jeff            
2 Jeff        Jeff             John            John        John            
3 John        John             0               Laura       0               
4 0           0                0               0           0               
5 0           0                0               0           0               
# ℹ 1 more variable: cdai_rem.eur <chr>

Created on 2024-04-23 with reprex v2.1.0
Personally, I would prefer to work with the resulting table from the third step.
Steps four and five are just to format it as you requested.
Oh, and you don't need five steps. Just pipe one to four if you want (but leave step five).
# new_df after step 3:
> new_df
# A tibble: 15 × 3
   id    value comb            
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>           
 1 Amy       1 crp_100.eur     
 2 Cindy     1 bmi_100.cdai_rem
 3 Jeff      1 bmi_100.cdai_rem
 4 Jeff      1 bmi_100.crp_100 
 5 Jeff      1 bmi_100.eur     
 6 Jeff      1 cdai_rem.crp_100
 7 Jeff      1 cdai_rem.eur    
 8 Jeff      1 crp_100.eur     
 9 John      1 bmi_100.cdai_rem
10 John      1 bmi_100.crp_100 
11 John      1 bmi_100.eur     
12 John      1 cdai_rem.crp_100
13 John      1 cdai_rem.eur    
14 John      1 crp_100.eur     
15 Laura     1 bmi_100.eur 

That's it, hope it helps!
